# How can installed packages of a Python project in Pycharm IDE be used in every new Projects

Tags: module, pycharm

Hello from the other side,

Python file on pycharm

I pip installed some packages using pycharm terminal: mysql connector, pymysql, pillow, etc needed for my programmes.

I have created some Python files and imported mysql connector, pymysql, PIL, etc and my codes worked fine.

Recently I tried creating a new python file in a new project, when I tried to import mysql connector and pymysql, my codes get red underline, notifying me that the imported modules can't be found.

These are the same packages I imported in my previous files and they worked fine.

So why are they turning red underline and greyed out now?

Do I need to be pip installing these packages for every new project?

I tried to see how I could resolve this by making some researches and asking some friends. I was advised to go to the settings and try to create a new environment with the installed packages of my choice, and then checking the boxes for global inheritance and making it available for other projects.

After this, the OK button was inactive (greyed), so I couldnt apply this change. I discovered I was notified that the enviroment rowbox wasnt empty and that I should use a new virtual environment which is empty but I really don't know how to create this.

Please if you've encountered something like this before or can assist, kindly give me a step-by-step approach.

Comment: That depends on where you installed the packages, if you installed them on your system python interpreter you can use them everywhere if you select your system interpreter. But I would suggest using an virtualenv to install packages. (You can set it up in settings->Project->interpreter) and you can make this virtualenv available to other projects

Comment: Thanks for your comment Tanja, plz would you mind giving me the step by step approach? I have gotten to the project interpreter settings but got stuck

Comment: Which system are you on? Pycharm sometimes behaves strange :) I do most Installation stuff with linux terminal

Comment: Windows 8 and 10 (2 laptops)

Comment: I added a step by step approach if something is missing/not possible on your system tell me. You could maybe add a screenshot of you project interpreter screen with the possible interpreters you have, maybe that helps to identify the problem

Comment: Especially on windows it could be that you do not have the correct rights in pycharm to install stuff on the 'system interpreter' so I would really suggest using a virtual environment. This is also good if you have different projects which require different setup. e.g. different package versions

Comment: I used both virtual and system environment but couldnt effect the change. I was told the environment wasnt empty. I tried sharing pictures with you but they are above 2.5mb. Can we use teamviewer plz? Are you on Facebook?

Comment: Did you run pycharm as administrator?

Comment: If you get the message the environment is not empty it means an environment with the name already exists. Try to use another name. If you don’t change it pycharm automatically creates a venv when you start a new project. So you could also select this one. Normally in your project folder name: venv

Comment: I think I'm missing out something and havent really understood how to create a new virtual environment to use.

Answer (score 3):

Open File -> Settings

Select Project Interpreter than go to the gear wheel in the upper right corner and select add.

Use Virtual Environment, select your prefered base Interpreter in my case 3.6 and add the name for the virtual environment and where you want to store it

If you don't need to I would suggest to not inherit global site packages
But you should select make it available to other projects.

Confirm it.
[image: Project Interpreter]

Afterwards the virtual env should be selected in project interpreter if not select it from the list. Right beside the List you see a plus, you can use this to add new packages with python (doesn't work all the time for me -> then use terminal)

[image: Selected Interpreter]

Comment: Thanks for this detailed explanation. As I said in my post, when I came to the project interpreter and checked the box to make the installed packages available for other projects, the OK button greyed out and became inactive

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of this screen? I try to test it on a win 10 system

Comment: Okay, kindly send me your Facebook id via cleojava@yahoo.com and plz let me know when you do

Comment: I'm sorry I slept off, let me check now and send you a Facebook message if your ID is there. Thanks.

Comment: I have been able to fix this a long time ago. The step by step approach guided me.

Answer (score 0):

I really thank everyone who made effort to attempt my question. After much trial, I was able to resolve it and I will post how I resolved it step-by-step to enable others like me understand better.

First, when installing our Pycharm, a folder is automatically created for storing every project we shall be working on, this folder becomes the database of our projects. In most cases, folder is stored in our C:\drive.

Now, open your pycharm window (I mean your working template),
File ----> open (this diplays the folders in your drive) ----> select the folder for storing your Pycharm projects and click ok. NOTE: do not open this folder to show your projects, just click on it and click ok. There are some situations whereby the Pycharm projects folder is already displayed on our pycharm window, this is because we already chose it during our installation. In a case like this, no need trying to bring it to the Projects displayed in our window as it'd already be displayed in the Projects in our window.

Your Pycharm projects folder will then display in your pycharm window under Projects.

Click on the Pycharm projects folder under your Projects and it will be highlighted blue.

Go to settings ----> Project: (your pycharm projects folder will also show here)
By the right, select Project interpreter.

Do your normal installation of packages by clicking on the + sign at the right extreme (that is if you haven't installed any package before)

Then configure your environment setting by making sure the boxes for inheriting global site packages and making this available to other projects are checked.

When configuring your environment setting for the pycharm projects folder, the location path should also end with your pycharm projects folder\venv ; please do not include the name of any particular project in the location path as doing this will make these changes effective in only that particular project files.

Then click ok.

Whatever project your create under the Pycharm projects folder will then inherit every packages you've installed in the pycharm project settings.

I believe this will help those who have been having difficulty resolving this.